# Why is the php function "metaphone" around 20x slower on windows than linux?

Tags: php, windows, metaphone

Does somebody know why php function "metaphone" is around 20x slower running on windows than Linux?
I tested with loop benchmark and results are:
0.123 sec for Linux php5
1.892 sec for windows php7

Math operations are almost equal.

Similar problem with `strtoupper` and `strtolower` both are 3-4 times slower on windows vs linux.

Comment: Same HARDWARE used? And the test is not so good at all because you are testing PHP 5 against PHP 7. Because there are not equal at all (7 has major changes). Do the same test with the same version and hardware.

Comment: And test on commmand line , not in the browser.

Comment: I tested also on php5 using windows, same results for same cpu speed. Thanks for suggestion, I will check with commad line. Edit: same results.